# point of UIViewController in IB

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

What exactly is the point of adding a UIViewController in IB? There is no way to add code like you can if you create a viewController in Xcode? And if you can what is the advantage of doing it in IB.

And isn't the whole point of a MVC to seperate code into "modular" parts so why would add a ViewController in IB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes all you need is a UIViewController. But most times you would create a UIViewController subclass of your own (in IB).

Comment: i thought a UIViewController was there to be subclassed, what is it's purpose otherwise

Comment: Presenting transitions, etc.  You can push a view onto a navigation controller, or present it from a tab bar without a view controller there.